# How to implement SSO in spring boot application with organisation ADFS oauth server?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, single-sign-on, adfs

I am trying to implement SSO in my application. After setting oauth properties, when trying to run it then with this url:

> https://[domain]/adfs/oauth2/authorize?client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/zd/login&response_type=code&state=cORYBy

I am getting this error:

> Activity ID: 00000000-0000-0000-5a6c-008000000090
>
> Error time: Wed, 26 Jul 2017 05:54:22 GMT
>
> Cookie: enabled
>
> User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36

I searched a lot on internet about it but not able to find any solution.

Comment: What does it say in the ADFS event log?

Comment: Actually we are using oauth server for ADFS. Our organisation use it for single sign on. So don't know about event log output.

Comment: What version of ADFS? This works on my ADFS 4.0 - https://my-adfs/adfs/oauth2/authorize?client_id=52...a9&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-pc%2FTodoListWebApp%2F&response_mode=query&scope=openid. You can do this from a browser.

Comment: Actually we don't know about ADFS version also. They just provide us client id, client secret, public key,access token uri and userAuthorizationUri. We configured but its not working and giving all above error.